Get type of root bson_t struct
I want to find out the type of a bson_t struct which I convert initially from a JSON string, e.g.
bson_t* newBJSONObj = bson_new_from_json("{ \"Name\": \"Obj\" }", -1, NULL);
bson_t* newBJSONArray = bson_new_from_json("[ \"ArrayEntry\" ]", -1, NULL);


if I use an iterator to find out the type:
bool IsBSONDocument(bson_t* aBSON)
{
  bson_iter_t iterBSON;
  bson_iter_init(&iterBSON, aBSON);
  bson_type_t rootType = bson_iter_type(&iterBSON); // 87 ?!?
  return rootType == BSON_TYPE_DOCUMENT;
}

This doesn't work, rootType will be an invalid value (e.g. 87) not a a valid entry of the bson_type_t enum
As I understand this is because you have to call bson_iter_next() so you can't use directly what is returned by bson_iter_init(); however calling bson_iter_next() will now point to the key-value pair "Name"-"Obj" (in case of newBJSONObj) and the type of this will be BSON_TYPE_UTF8, not BSON_TYPE_DOCUMENT which is the type of the root I want to find out; The same goes for newBJSONArray: calling bson_iter_next() will point to the first key-value "0"-"ArrayEntry" whose type again will be utf8, not array.
